Are there any cases of freely shared technology in the Star Trek Universe?
This (and other) questions discuss technologically similar civilizations in the Star Trek Universe.
I believe the following question is different: Are there any cases of technology being freely shared among different planets before the Federation was formed or from planets outside the Federation?

People of the Federation go to the same schools (like Starfleet Academy), work in the same research organizations...  It's not about sharing technology, it's about collectively developing it.

What do you mean by "sharing?"  Does industrial/military espionage count?  Reverse engineering?  Inspiration?

difficult to understand how "sharing" can be interpreted as "industrial/military espionage count"

It depends on your perspective.  If you're a party whose technology is being copied, it may not look like "sharing" to you, but to a third party it's indistinguishable from you teaching the technology.

@DavidW the qualifier "freely" when talking about a thing being shared very definitely means you are doing it intentionally and willingly

@Andrew That word was added 4 hours after I asked my question.

Pre-Frederation, the Friendship One probe was an attempt to freely "share" technology, such as scientific and communication technology, possibly even antimatter and warp drive technology, with others species in the galaxy.
B'Elanna specifically describes it as a "How To" manual.
It did not go well.
Additionally, after first contact, the Vulcans may have shared some (non-weapon) technology freely with humanity to help them recover from WWIII and use on early ships (e.g. artificial gravity comes to mind).
The Vulcans also shared their "star charts" to get the NX-01 to Qo'noS, although they required T'Pol to go along.

The USS Defiant from Deep Space Nine was built using a cloaking device that was shared with the Federation by the Romulan Empire.

In exchange for intelligence on the Dominion. And with restrictions on use, so not very freely. But still worth an up-tick.

It's not clear how this happened, but the Romulans are known to have used Klingon technology during the TOS period, which may count as non-Federation sharing.
From The Enterprise Incident following entry into the Romulan Neutral Zone:

SCOTT: That's a Klingon ship! But it couldn't be, not in this area.


SPOCK: Intelligence reports Romulans now using Klingon design.


TNG Suspicions
The Altine Conference was attended by the Federation and a Klingon and Ferengi.
https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Suspicions_(episode)
"A Ferengi scientist, Dr. Reyga, has created a metaphasic shielding technique and had presented it at the Altine Conference, but his unorthodox methods have left most scientists in the field ignoring his work."
TOS Friday's Child
In the original series the prime directive doesn't appear to be as strict about pre-warp civilizations. Starfleet will negotiate trade, Peace Corps type help, and possibly offer membership in exchange for dilithium or other scarce minerals. Especially if the Klingons are competing for the same planets.

SCOTT: How long were you stationed on the planet, Doctor?
MCCOY: Only a few months. We found them totally uninterested in medical aid or hospitals.

